# Issue in Custom Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the below code i have added a controller to store the name which can be used in child scope without use of prelinks.But still the name value is undefined.Where am i going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

<head>
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <parent></parent>
</body>
<script>
  var test1 = angular.module("test", []);
  test1.directive("child", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: "<div>{{message1}}</div>",
      link: function(scope, ctrl) {
        scope.message1 = "i m child of " + ctrl.name;
      }
    }
  });
  test1.directive("parent", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: "<div style='color:red'>{{message}}{{name}}" + "<child></child>" + "   </div>",
      link: function(scope, ctrl) {
        scope.name = ctrl.name;
        alert(ctrl.name);
        scope.message = "hi i am parent ";
      },
      controller: function() {
        this.name = "aditya";
      }
    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: got to the following link n see.

http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/gzbq2151/

here the link and controller functions basically get the same scope.

also if the directive is not isolated scope then it inherits parent scope.
I have removed instances of controller from your link functions. And added $scope in your controller.

Comment: Actually in ctrl @ link function you will get element not your controller for more information see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @F5'ed is very correct. link function accepts a minimum of 3 parameters, scope, element and attribute. As a fourth parameter you can get controller of the directive you mention as "require". And if you mention a directive as "require" then you are basically saying your directive is dependant on the required directive and if the required directive is not provided it will throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you declared the parent controller using `controller as` syntax, `this`, you can add `controllerAs` option to your directive and define a name of the controller:

```
var test1 = angular.module("test", []);

test1.directive("child", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: "<div>{{message1}}</div>",
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.message1 = "i m child of " + scope.parentCtrl.name;
      }
    }
  });

test1.directive("parent", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: "<div style='color:red'>{{message}}{{name}}" + "<child></child>" + "   </div>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.name = ctrl.name;
        alert(scope.name);
        scope.message = "hi i am parent ";
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        this.name = "aditya";
      },
        controllerAs: 'parentCtrl' // Name of the controller
    }
  });
```

Then, in your child, you can access the parent scope by using its defined name, `scope.parentCtrl.name`.